# AXIOS VueJs passing response parameter within v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I have creating **VueJs** application and passing API calls using **AXIOS**. Within current scenario user is able to click a button, which will execute function and display list of all unique manufacturers. Within the list a button is assigned, which should let user to see all the models under the manufacturer. As of yer I am unsure how to connect to functions so when clicking on one object it will return user a filter view where models assigned to manufacturer will be showed.

Below I have displayed my code

**VueJs**

```
    <div v-for="(manufacturerResponse) in manufacturerResponse ">

    <p> <b>Manufacturer ID {{manufacturerResponse.manufacturerId}} </b> 
<b-btn variant="warning" v-on:click="show(); getModels(response.manufactuerId);">View Models</b-btn>

</p>


    </div>
```

**AXIOS - getManufacturer, which displays only unique Manufacturers**

```
    getManufacturers () {
            AXIOS.get(`/url/`)
                .then(response => {
                    console.log(this.manufacturerResponse)

                    this.response = response.data

                    this.manufacturerResponse = []
                    response.data.forEach(item => {

                        if (!this.manufacturerResponse.some(fltr => {
                            return item.manufacturerId == fltr.manufacturerId
                        })) {
                            this.manufacturerResponse.push(item);
                        }
                    });
                })
        },
```

**AXIOS - getModel, which displays models under Manufacturer**

```
 getModels () {

            AXIOS.get(`/url/`)
                .then(response => {

                    const id = 0;

                    this.testResponse = response.data.filter (kp6 => kp6.manufacturerId === this.manufacturerResponse[id].manufacturerId );

                    console.log(this.testResponse)

                })

        },
```

If it helps also added example how the response appears in the simple array

```
[
{"id":1,"manufacturerId":1,"model":"Focus"},
{"id":2,"manufacturerId":1,"model":"Transit"},
{"id":3,"manufacturerId":2,"model":"Clio"},
{"id":4,"manufacturerId":3,"model":"Niva"},
{"id":5,"manufacturerId":3,"model":"Yaris"},
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In template you have below:

```
v-on:click="show(); getModels(response.manufactuerId);"
```

But it should be:

```
v-on:click="show(); getModels(manufacturerResponse.manufacturerId);"
```

since `manufacturerResponse.manufacturerId` is the id you are currently displaying and the button click should get the models for that id.

`getModels()` would receive that param like `getModels(manufacturerId)` then use that to filter as below:

```
this.testResponse = response.data.filter (kp6 => kp6.manufacturerId === manufacturerId);
```

Answer (score 0):

The **show()** method should be setup to accept a parameter of **response.manufactuerId**

So ...

```
v-on:click="show(response.manufacturerId);"
```

Now... inside your Vue instance

you will need to make sure the method for show looks something like this...

```
show(manufacturerId){
    this.getModels(manufacturerId) // This will call the getModels method on the Vue instance and pass in the manufacturerId that you provided via your click event
}
```

You can probably just bypass the show method and just have the click event call getModels directly and pass in the manufacturerId directly.

Comment: the show appears to have been misleading as it controls the modal in which the results will be displayed

Comment: Either way... you need to add an argument to your getModels method.... getModels(id) .... you can then use this id to pass into your axios api call.